# iPhone Album Art Effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, itunes, effect

I'm just wondering here if there is an in-built view for this. I haven't managed to find it, but then I may not be looking in the right places.

I'm trying to find the effect used in the Album Art view of Music (or iPod) on the iPod Touch (or iPhone/iPad). The effect that scrolls between multiple album covers, pushing all other ones behind it. I'd like to use this effect for a very different scenario, and I'm happy to create it myself - but it seems it is also used in the App Store application on the iPad, so I'm wondering if it's built-in. If not, it must be a private API used by Apple.

Note: I'm NOT talking about the effect of flipping the image. I'm referring to the effect of scrolling between multiple album covers, with the current album cover being foremost and rotated correctly, and with all other album covers in the 'stacked' rotation behind it. This is the view you automatically see when rotating an iPod Touch or iPhone into landscape mode when using the Music app or the iPod app.

Also, this is part of an iPhone application developed in Xcode. It is NOT a web application.

Anyone know if it's part of any public APIs, or will I have to write my own custom effect?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Do you mean "Coverflow"? Google it.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're looking for is called Cover Flow and it's a private API. There are a few tutorials around the web for how to make one yourself. [Here's one by Bill Dudney](http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdcora/creating-a-compelling-user-interface-with-core-animation) (a video tutorial)

Comment: Thanks nevan; I'll look into the effect and work on it. I'd vote up your response, but I can't yet. When I can, I'll come back to it!